# Setting up Dual Boot System from Zero. UEFI

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I need to reestructure everything in order to use UEFI. My main operating system will be Ubuntu but I'll need to use Windows 10 exceptionally (and I can't use a VM). I'll need to have an NTFS partition to share data.
I haven't done this sort of set up in ages and remembered there were a lot of caveats in order to have it working in UEFI systems.
I have a 256GB disk. Can you recommend me a full setup of the partitions and how would the process be like ?

Comment: It should just work, and you are welcome to watch all of the dual boot howtos on youtube.

Comment: [This method](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/) works well. Make sure W10 is installed first.